# I deleted MIME directories and update-mime-database doesn't work anymore! Help!

Tags: command-line, rm, mime-type

`update-mime-database` was getting very slow recently, so I decided to remove all associations and start over, thus I ran:

```
sudo rm -fr /usr/share/mime /usr/share/mime-info /usr/share/mimelnk
```

I thought that `update-mime-database` would notice that and just create blank directories instead, but it didn't and instead complains: `"directory '/usr/share/mime/packages' does not exist!"`.

What do I do?

Comment: Reinstall the `shared-mime-info` package?

Comment: [This bug report](https://github.com/wavded/gedit-coffeescript/issues/38) for an unrelated library suggests that they fixed it by just doing a `mkdir -p /usr/share/mime/packages`. But I agree that you should just reinstall the package.

Comment: @steeldriver Tanks! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr/share/mime` directory and its `/usr/share/mime/packages` subdirectory are provided by package `shared-mime-info` so to fix the error it should be sufficient to re-install the package - either from your favorite GUI package manager or from the command line using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall shared-mime-info
```

If you want to restore `/usr/share/mime-info` and `/usr/share/mimelnk` as well, then they appear to belong to `libreoffice-common`

Other packages may have installed their own files underneath `/usr/share/mime` - to identify these, you can use

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/mime
```